# Dovecot Authenticating with Active Directory, username with period not going through

Tags: active-directory, postfix, ldap, dovecot, roundcube

I have been struggling the past 2 days. My conf file is like this:

```
hosts           = 192.168.2.2
ldap_version    = 3
auth_bind_userdn = %Ln
auth_bind       = yes
dn              = admin
dnpass          = mypass
base            = cn=users,dc=example, dc=com
scope           = subtree
deref           = never
user_attrs = homeDirectory=home,uidNumber=uid,gidNumber=gid
user_filter = (sAMAccountName=%Ln)
pass_filter = (sAMAccountName=%Ln)
iterate_attrs = uid=user
iterate_filter = (objectClass=person)
default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
```

When I have a username like timothy@example.com it works, yet tim.tim@example.com fails.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you have "separator = ." ?
I am afraid that this can't work, dovecot is not able to guess where the username ends and where starts folder name.
Check namespace/separator in 10-mail.conf
Default: is ‘.’
Try ‘/’ for separator.
https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/namespace/

Comment: Thank you very much @nih. I have gone through this and added '/' as a seperator, but unfortunately I still cannot pass a username with a period like tim.tim@example.com